# is there way to use caml to do something like a full-text search on a list

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Is there a way to use SharePoint CAML to do a Full-Text search on a sharepoint list?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the actual full-text search using the search object model and just limit it to the list by adding the path condition to the Where clause

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the contains keyword, try looking at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196501.aspx